List files and folders of an application and get the CHMOD of each using RecursiveIteratorIterator
I am trying to get an overview of the permissions (chmod) of all files and folders of my application ( www.placido-shop.com ). The goal is to check and/or set permissions when installing the program or updating it, in order to provide maximum security.
I tried this but it only returns permissions for files and not for folders:
  <?php 

  // test 1
  define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

  // iterator
  $it =
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( ROOT,
                RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));

  // loop iterator
  foreach( $it as $file ) {

      $chmod = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($it->getSubPathName())), -4);
      
      // if( $chmod == '0644' ) continue;
      
      echo $it->getSubPathName().'<br>';
      
      echo ' - chmod: '.$chmod.'<br><br>';

  }

  ?>

I also tried this to get folder permissions:
  <?php 

  define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

  $ARR_dir  = array_diff(scandir(ROOT), array('.', '..'));

  foreach ( $ARR_dir as $file ) {
    
     echo $file.' : '. substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4).'<br>';
  }

  ?>

I would like to get a mix of both methods using the first test with RecursiveIteratorIterator.
Thanks for your help and feedback,
Best regards,
Raf.
Correcting the code for the correct solution :
  <?php 

  define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

  // iterator
  $it =
   new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
     new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(ROOT,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
   RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

  // loop iterator
  foreach( $it as $file ) {

     $chmod = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($it->getSubPathName())), -4);
     echo $it->getSubPathName().'<br>';
     echo ' - chmod: '.$chmod.'<br><br>';

  }

  ?>


Use the RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST flag for RecursiveIteratorIterator to include the directories.

@Barmar ->  Ho Yeah ! - Thank you ! It was so simple... My brain was confused by these imbrications.

On the other hand, I would remove the "Duplicate" flag because the code presented is more elegant in my opinion.

If I remove the duplicate flag, then someone will have to answer this question with essentially the same code as in the duplicate.
